# MYSql search in concated columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks something like this

```
products_table
        ID | code | product_variants_id | product_name | variants     | variants_value   
        1  |     1|  123451             | beer cake    | color        | blue
        2  |     1|  123451             | beer cake    | temperature  | hot
        3  |     1|  123451             | beer cake    | weight       | 0.5
        4  |     2|  123453             | ad wrap      | color        | green
        5  |     2|  123453             | ad wrap      | weight       | 1
```

I ran the below query to get unique rows for products with the respective variants.

```
SELECT xx.code, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(xx.variants,':',xx.variants_value)) 
AS variants_and_values, xx.product_name, xx.product_variants_id
FROM products_table xx
GROUP BY xx.product_variants_id, xx.product_name, xx.code
```

The below table is obtained as a result of the above query.Now i can simply run through this table and display the products.

```
       code | product_variants_id   | product_name |  variants_and_values                 
         1  |   123451              | beer cake    | color:blue,temperature:hot,weight:0.5
         2  |   123453              | ad wrap      | color:green,weight:1
```

Now the real question is that ,If i were to search through the above table and to display only those products with the variant as  `hot` , how am i gonna do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from t where variants like '%:hot' or variants like '%:hot,%'
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simple to write `%:hot%` ?

Comment: And of the text is **hotio**? You should ignore **hot** as a prefix

Comment: fair enough,my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT T.*
FROM(
SELECT xx.code, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(xx.variants,':',xx.variants_value)) 
AS variants_and_values, xx.product_name, xx.product_variants_id
FROM products_table xx
GROUP BY xx.product_variants_id, xx.product_name, xx.code
) T
WHERE T.variants_and_values LIKE '%:hot' OR T.variants_and_values LIKE '%:hot,'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT xx.code, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(xx.variants,':',xx.variants_value)) 
AS variants_and_values, xx.product_name, xx.product_variants_id
FROM products_table xx
WHERE (xx.variants  = 'temperature' AND xx.variants_value = 'hot') 
GROUP BY xx.product_variants_id, xx.product_name, xx.code
```